# how to display files that start and end with certain letters?

Tags: ls, wildcards

Write the ls command that will display all the filenames of files in the current directory that start with the letter *f* or *F* and end with the letter *g* or *G*.

Comment: have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: You can't do that with `ls`, at least not if there are also directories or other things that also fulfil those criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -1 --file-type [fF]*[gG] | grep -v /$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell `ls` to only list names of files (i.e. not directories).  You can, however, do this with `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname 'f*g'
```

This requires a `find` implementation that knows about `-maxdepth` and `-iname` (most do).

---

Minor nitpick: `f` and `F` are the same letters, but different characters.

Comment: Then use `[fF]*[gG]` instead of `f*g`!

Comment: @cylgalad Then when? `-iname` does case-insensitive matching.